# Solving non-homogeneous second order differential that have square root

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution for $y''+ 10y' = t^2$

I managed to get the homogeneous part, but how do I solve for the nonhomogeneous right hand part? What do I have to substitute in for the case of a square root? 
will $at^2$ works?

Comment: Maybe try a general cubic and see what coefficient constraints come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the rule of thumb is to seek particular solution in the same form as right hand side of the equation.
Since your inhomogeneous term is $t^2$ I would look for a solution in form of polynomial.

Indeed, if we substitute $y^*(t):= at^3 + bt^2 +ct +d$ into equation $y''+ 10y' = t^2$ we will get

\begin{align}
6at + 2b + 10\left(3at^2+2bt+c\right)  = t^2
\end{align}

Collecting coefficients in front of powers of $t$ we get
$$
\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
30a &= 1\\
6a +20b &= 0\\
10c &=0
\end{aligned}\right.
\implies
\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
a &= {1}/{30}\\
b &= -{1}/{100}\\
c &=0
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

Thus the particular solution of your equation takes form

\begin{align}
\bbox[1ex, border:solid 1.5pt #e10000]{y^*(t):= \dfrac{t^3}{30} - \dfrac{t^2}{100} + d}
\end{align}

where $d$ is a constant.

Comment: This, however, doesn't always work. You may need to look at the homogeneous solution in order to make an educated guess. (Here, that means you would have tried $y^*(t)=(at^2+bt+c)\cdot t$, the $at^2+bt+c$ because the original RHS is a polynomial of degree 2; the $t$ because $y=C$ is a solution to the homogeneous equation.

Comment: @CarlHeckman Yes, I agree. That is why I started my answer with the _"rule of thumb"_ disclaimer :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a general method for solving linear ODEs called [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters). It is a bit of work by hand, but is 'guaranteed' in that there is no guessing involved (assuming you can solve the associated homogenous ODE). The linked wikipedia article also has a [section that specifically discusses second-order ODEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#General_second_order_equation), like the one you're asking about. Let's try it out.

We have that the associated homogenous ODE is $y'' + 10y'=0$, so we solve $\lambda^2+10\lambda = 0$ to find $\lambda = 0,-10$. Homogenous solutions can be thus taken as $y_1(x) = c_1$ and $y_2(x)=c_1e^{-10x}$. For simplicity, let's take $y_1(x) = 1$ and $y_2(x) = e^{-10x}$; notice we must choose linearly independent homogenous solutions for the method, so that in particular we may not choose a zero solution.

We will now look for a particular solution of the form $$y_p(x) = a(x) \cdot y_1(x) + b(x) \cdot y_2(x) = a(x)+ b(x) \cdot e^{-10x}$$where $a,b$ are unknown functions. We further impose the condition $a'\cdot y_1 + b'\cdot y_2 = 0$, that is, $a'(x)+b'(x)\cdot e^{-10x} = 0$. Differentiating $y_p$ yields:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
{y_p}'(x)&=a'(x)+b'(x)\cdot e^{-10x}-10b(x)\cdot e^{-10x}\\
&=-10b(x)\cdot e^{-10x}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Differentiating again gives us:

\begin{equation}
{y_p}''(x)=-10b'(x)\cdot e^{-10x}+100b(x)\cdot e^{-10x}
\end{equation}

So that, if $y_p$ is a solution to $y''+10y' = x^2$ it satisfies$$-10b'(x)e^{-10x} = x^2$$or $b'(x)=-\frac{1}{10}x^2\cdot e^{10x}$. This is a very easy first-order ODE, and yields$$b(x)=e^{10x}\cdot\left ( -\frac{1}{100}x^2+\frac{1}{500}x-\frac{1}{5000}\right ) + C$$

From $a'(x)+b'(x)\cdot e^{-10x} = 0$, we also get that $a'(x) = \frac{1}{10}x^2$, so $a(x) = \frac{1}{30}x^3 + C$. Hence, a particular solution, taking $C=0$ in both $a$ and $b$, is given by

\begin{equation}
y_p(x)=\frac{1}{30}x^3+ -\frac{1}{100}x^2+\frac{1}{500}x-\frac{1}{5000}
\end{equation}

You can check that $y_p$ is indeed a particular solution to the ODE.

I know this sounds really complicated, and is definitely a lot more work than 'guessing' the correct particular solution. That said, if the inhomogenous term gets a little more complicated, guessing can become really hard and this method will always yield an answer. You may have to solve some ugly integrals, but even then the worst you get is an answer in terms of integrals of **known** functions (provided, of course, that you know homogenous solutions).